# Django: grabbing parameters

Tags: django, parameters

I'm having the hardest time with what should be super simple. I can't grab the passed parameters in django.

In the browser I type:

http://localhost:8000/mysite/getst/?term=hello

My url pattern is:

(r'^mysite/getst/$', 'tube.views.getsearchterms')

My View is

def getsearchterms(request):

```
my_term = some_way_to_get_term

return HttpResponse(my_term)
```

In this case it should return "hello". I am calling the view, but a blank value is returned to me. I've tried various forms of GET....

What should some_way_to_get_term be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get parameters can be accesses like any dictionary:

```
my_term = request.GET['term']
my_term = request.GET.get('term', 'my default term')
```

Comment: Well, that worked :) I thought I tried that, but I guess not ;)

Comment: Actually, I get an error, UnicodeDecodeError, with some parameters, for example:  http://localhost:8000/my_site/getst/?term=telet. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Actually, I see now that the issue isn't with getting the parameter, but what I do with it. I use it in a url and then do data = urllib2.urlopen(url) and  j = json.load(data). So the issue may be with something that is returned. So, it's not related to this question. I'll look into it and post another question if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

By using arbitrary arguments after ? and then catching them with request.GET['term'], you're missing the best features of Django urls module : a consistent URL scheme

If "term" is always present in this URL call it must be meaningful to your application, 
so your url rule could look like :

```
(r'^mysite/getst/(?P<term>[a-z-.]+)/', 'tube.views.getsearchterms')
```

That means :

1. That you've got a more SEO-FRIENDLY AND stable URL scheme (no ?term=this&q=that inside)
2. That you can catch your argument easily in your view :

Like this

```
def getsearchterms(request,term):
    #do wahtever you want with var term
    print term
```